# Docker: Open Container port only to Host and other Containers on it, without opening to the internet

Tags: docker, networking

I'm making a sample ETL app for learning purposes. I want to have 2 containers: a MySQL Container, and a Python container running with Redis to serve the data.

I want to open ports on these containers, but I don't want to open them to the internet for obvious security reasons.

If I open ports on these containers, will they remain only open to the Host machine, or does the Host machine also have to open these ports?

Comment: no host machine need not open ports in firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have any Compose `ports:` or `docker run -p` options, the containers will be able to communicate with each other but will not be reachable from the host or off-host.  A sample Compose setup:

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports: ['8080:8080']  # the application itself is visible
    environment:
      PGHOST: postgres    # using normal Docker inter-container communication
      REDIS_HOST: redis
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    # no ports:
  redis:
    image: redis:6
    # no ports:
```

You can also set `ports:` with an optional bind address.  If that address is 127.0.0.1, then the published port will be reachable from non-container processes on the host system.  Other hosts will not be able to connect to it, and containers will not be able to use the host gateway address or `host.docker.internal` to connect to it.

```yaml
services:
  postgres:
    # from non-container processes on the host,
    # PGHOST=localhost PGPORT=54321 reaches this container
    #
    # from other containers in this Compose file,
    # PGHOST=postgres PGPORT=5432 still works
    ports: ['127.0.0.1:54321:5432']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close external access to your container, specify the IP when you launch the docker container:

```
sudo docker run -p 127.0.0.1:9000:9000 ...
```